# Convert list of strings into pandas DataFrame based on values in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of strings like the following:

```
input = ["number__128_alg__hello_min_n__7_max_n__9_full_seq__True_random_color__False_shuffle_shapes__False.pkl", "k__9_window__10_number__128_overlap__True_alg__hi_min_n__7_max_n__9_full_seq_embedding__False_random_color__False_shuffle_shapes__False.pkl", "k__9_window__10_number__128_overlap__True_alg__what_random_color__False_shuffle_shapes__False.pkl"]
```

The format of these strings is parameter name followed by "__", then parameter value. After the parameter value, there is a _ before the next parameter name. It is worth noting that some parameter names contain _ in them (such as "random_shape". Each string has different parameters, but there is overlap. Therefore, I would like to make a data frame with each parameter name as a column, and each row being the values corresponding to each element of the `input` list. If the particular value in the list does not have a parameter, the data frame should contain NA or NaN or anything.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

EDIT: If it cannot be done for the original list, what about:

```
input = ["number__128_alg__hello_min.n__7_max.n__9_full.seq__True_random.color__False_shuffle.shapes__False.pkl", "k__9_window__10_number__128_overlap__True_alg__hi_min.n__7_max.n__9_full.seq__False_random.color__False_shuffle.shapes__False.pkl", "k__9_window__10_number__128_overlap__True_alg__what_random.color__False_shuffle.shapes__False.pkl"]
```

Comment: If you didn't have `_` in the parameter names this is easy, given that requirement, it's virtually impossible to ascertain which ones are separators and which ones are just in parameter names.

Comment: If it was just a period instead of the underscore in the parameter names, would it be possible?

Comment: Yes, it would be simple then.  The separator just needs to be something that can't appear in your column names.

Comment: Some of the inputs are not clear， take this for instance: alg__hi_min_n__7, it could mean {"alg": "hi", "min_n": 7} or  {"alg": "hi_min", "n": 7}, while quite difficult to tell, right?

Comment: Could you suggest an answer based on my edit? The underscores in parameter names were replaced with periods.

Comment: @chrisz It is possible to know which ones are separators but only if parameter names can have `_` in them but values not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if you assume values can't contain the `_` character (also assuming you want to discard the `.pkl` in the end).

```
input = [
    "number__128_alg__hello_min_n__7_max_n__9_full_seq_embedding__True_random_color__False_shuffle_shapes__False.pkl", 
    "k__9_window__10_number__128_overlap__True_alg__hi_min_n__7_max_n__9_full_seq_embedding__False_random_color__False_shuffle_shapes__False.pkl", 
    "k__9_window__10_number__128_overlap__True_alg__what_random_color__False_shuffle_shapes__False.pkl"
]
```

A simple regular expression should do the trick:

```
import re
data = [dict(re.findall(r"([^_].*?)__([^_]+)", _[:-4])) for _ in input]
print(data)
```

Result:

```
[{'number': '128',
  'alg': 'hello',
  'min_n': '7',
  'max_n': '9',
  'full_seq_embedding': 'True',
  'random_color': 'False',
  'shuffle_shapes': 'False'},
 {'k': '9',
  'window': '10',
  'number': '128',
  'overlap': 'True',
  'alg': 'hi',
  'min_n': '7',
  'max_n': '9',
  'full_seq_embedding': 'False',
  'random_color': 'False',
  'shuffle_shapes': 'False'},
 {'k': '9',
  'window': '10',
  'number': '128',
  'overlap': 'True',
  'alg': 'what',
  'random_color': 'False',
  'shuffle_shapes': 'False'}]
```

As a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]